# Is Binance API Key part of RSA key pair?

Tags: pkcs11, cryptocurrency, binance

When we generate an API key in Binance there is a generated secret key too. I could not find any reference that those are RSA key pairs. They could be just random unrelated numbers. Is the Binance API Key the public key of RSA key pairs?

Comment: It's doubtful that these are RSA keypairs.  See the example at https://cryptopro.app/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/6.copy-your-keys-to-crypto-pro-min-1024x734.png.  The secret key is approx 60 base-58 characters.  That translates to somewhere in the neighborhood of 350 bits.  RSA private keys are typically much longer than this (1024 bits or longer).

Comment: Only the Binance-developer can say whether this secret key is aktually part of anything or not.

Comment: Dear @anion, I think mti2935 's comment is logical. Typical RSA key lengths are not consistent with what we get from key pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This answer pertains not only to this question, but also to your earlier question at [Using two different random numbers instead of RSA Keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/263551/using-two-different-random-numbers-instead-of-rsa-keys).

The `api key` and the `secret key` are not an asymmetric key pair.  This can be seen by looking at an example of how these keys are used to access the API, for example, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984654/binance-api-keys.

You'll notice that if you follow the code in the top-voted answer, that the `api key` is included in the request, then to authenticate the request, an HMAC of the request is generated using the `secret key`.

In order to validate the request, the server would have to verify the HMAC.  HMAC's rely on symmetric cryptography, not asymmetric cryptography.  In other words, in order to validate the request, the server would have to know the `api key`.  This is in contrast to a digital signature used in asymmetric cryptography, where the private key is used to sign the request, and the public key is used to verify the signature.

Another way to think of this is that this is akin to a login function, where the `api key` is akin to the username, and the `secret key` is akin the password.  But, unlike a login function, the password is not sent across the wire in this case, it's used as the key to an HMAC function over the request.

See https://aspsecuritykit.net/guides/implementing-hmac-scheme-to-protect-api-requests/ for some interesting reading on this method of authentication with an API.

Comment: Yes, Binance uses HMAC to hash query string but uses the private key to hash. There are no singing or encryption by key pairs.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18572/is-it-okay-for-api-secret-to-be-stored-in-plain-text-or-decrypt-able, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38566/how-is-storing-an-api-secret-key-in-plaintext-in-a-database-secure, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180345/do-i-need-to-hash-or-encrypt-api-keys-before-storing-them-in-a-database for some interesting reading on this subject, especially the answer by Nick Sloan in the first link above.